# How can I run an example as part of `cargo test`?

Tags: testing, rust, rust-cargo

I have a Rust library with an example, and I want to test against the example as an indirect way to verify my library code.

I want to use `assert_cmd` as described in [this tutorial](https://rust-cli.github.io/book/tutorial/testing.html) to perform the test, however I cannot structure it in a way such that `cargo test` or `cargo test --example ...` will also build and update the example binary.

The test runs, but often times it is run with a stale version of the example binary. The example project also gets built, which I know because if I add `compile_error!` in the code, it will not let me run the tests. But for some reason the binary executed by `Command::cargo_bin(...)` is not updated.

Is there some configuration I am missing that can be used to convince cargo to rebuild the example binary?

Here's my directory structure:

```
project-dir
  - examples
    - example_one
      - main.rs
      - test.rs
  - src
    - lib.rs
  - Cargo.toml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a topic from IRLO discussing the problem that examples aren't build when running `cargo test` or `cargo test --examples`: https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/examples-and-tests/14347. Quote from this topic:

> Unfortunately there isn't a good story for automated testing of example programs. The examples are not guaranteed to be built for an integration test.

That being said `assert_cmd` has [this section](https://docs.rs/assert_cmd/latest/assert_cmd/cargo/index.html#limitations) in its documentation about its limitations. To quote:

> Only works with cargo binaries (cargo test ensures they are built).

Now the problem you are facing is that `cargo test` does not ensure that examples are built.

`assert_cmd` urges you to use [`escargot`](https://docs.rs/escargot/latest/escargot/index.html) when you run into its limitations, which has a more flexible API. AFAICT you can use `escargot` like this to build and run an example (see documentation [here](https://docs.rs/escargot/latest/escargot/struct.CargoBuild.html#method.example)):

```rust
extern crate escargot;

escargot::CargoBuild::new()
    .example("example_fixture")
    .manifest_path("tests/fixtures/example/Cargo.toml")
    .exec()
    .unwrap();
```

I hope this will allow you to test your examples properly.